# Countdown Timer Broadcast with Socket.io and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, countdowntimer

I am building a new version of my app with Node.js. Below you will find my winner countdown, where the output of `console.log(counter)`, needs to be broadcasted with Socket.io to all clients.

```
var counter = 10;
var WinnerCountdown = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(counter);
  counter--

  if (counter === 0) {
    console.log("Congratulations You WON!!");
    clearInterval(WinnerCountdown);
  }
}, 1000);
```

My Socket.IO code is as follows:

```
setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);
```

What should I replace the `new Date().toTimeString()`, so that it will show the message of console.log instead?

Comment: I think you want to move the state (in this case `counter`) to the server-side code (the second snippet). Then the client-side can have zero logic other than to listen for an event from the server and `console.log(result)`.

Answer (score 4):

To broad cast to all clients you can use `io.sockets.emit('counter', counter);`. Here is an example of a script you could use to achieve what (I think) you are trying to do:

#### server.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var counter = 10;
  var WinnerCountdown = setInterval(function(){
    io.sockets.emit('counter', counter);
    counter--
    if (counter === 0) {
      io.sockets.emit('counter', "Congratulations You WON!!");
      clearInterval(WinnerCountdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

#### client.js

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('counter', function(count){
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(count));
});
```

Hope this helps, please comment if you have any follow up questions!